# HP DL180 and External SAS Tape Backup Drive

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sas, tapedrive

Is is possible to use the following PCI-E card with a HP DL180 server (specifically the 487507-371 model) - HP 4x Internal/4x External SAS PCI-E Adapter (416096-B2).

If not what are the options for attaching an external SAS tape drive?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that will work just fine assuming you've got an open PCI-E slot (the server has 2 full height, and 1 low-profile). The cable is going to depend on exactly what type of tape drive you're connecting it to. If you edit in the Tape part number I can find the cable for you too.